# How to get the current directory within a meteor Smart Package

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I am building a package for meteor to be published on Atmosphere and I need to get the current directory that the package is installed. I have tried `process.cwd()` in a file that's included in the package, but that gets the current directory of my app. The package is installed and working correctly, it just seems that the package is running in the same process as the app, hence `process.cwd()` is getting the current app dir. Does anyone know of a trick to get the current directory of the package?

This is what I have in the package files:

package.js

```
Package.on_use(function (api) {
    api.use('sync-methods', 'server');
    api.add_files(["lib/api_server.js"], "server");
    api.add_files(["lib/api_client.js"], "client");
});
```

api_server.js

```
var cwd = process.cwd();
console.log(cwd);
```

This displays `/home/dknell/meteor-apps/testApp`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I obtain the path of a file in a Meteor package?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435797/how-do-i-obtain-the-path-of-a-file-in-a-meteor-package)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the content, but an absolute path for another tool, you can try

```
var path = Npm.require('path');
var base = path.resolve('.');
var assetsBase = path.join(base, '/assets/packages/<author_smart-package-name>');
```

For the <author_smart-package-name> enter your package name, but if it has your meteor user name included, change the colon (:) to underscore (_)

That seems okay on OS X and Linux, probably works in windows as well.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need current directory? To access a file inside the package? Then add a file as n package asset:

```
api.add_files(['file.txt'], 'server', {isAsset: true});
```

And then you can read it with `Assets.getText('file.txt')` in your package.

Answer (score 0):

oops, this is for files within the app, not a package. anyway maybe helpful to someone

I need to access a directory path for loading a list of files

```
// files in /private get built to:
//      .meteorlocal/build/programs/server/assets/app/
// base path resolves to:
//      .meteor/local/build/programs/server
```

so you need to manually add "/assets/app" to your paths.

until meteor change this at some point.

just getting to the content of a file isn't helpful if you have a directory of changing content...