# how to get the current directory of a package file

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, package, fs

How do i find the current path of the executing file when its in a meteor package?

I have a meteor package that needs to dynamically include a list of assets. 
the `fs.readdirSync` command needs a full path it seems.

when running the package inside an app, things are fine, as the path to the package is easily deduced. Like this:

```
  var path = Npm.require("path");
  var fs = Npm.require("fs");

  // normally found inside an app/packages dir like:
  var packagePath = path.join(path.resolve("."), "packages", "reactive-ace");  
  var srcPath = path.join(packagePath, "vendor", "ace", "src")  // files rel to package root
  var files = fs.readdirSync(srcPath);

  files.forEach(function(file){
    console.log("add_file", file)
    if (file === "snippets"){return;}
    addPath = path.join("vendor", "ace", "src", file);
    api.add_files(addPath, "client", {isAsset: true});
  });
```

However, when i am local developing, using $PACKAGE_DIRS - the package repo is actually somewhere remote on my system. But I'm unable to deduce this just from the package.js

I tried `__dirname` and also `require.main.filename` but these both are unknown in the context of building a meteor package.

My current hack involves parsing `process.env.PACKAGE_DIRS` but that is ugly.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the current directory within a meteor Smart Package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721351/how-to-get-the-current-directory-within-a-meteor-smart-package)